# How can I write to strings.xml file string-array style in Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

I want to list a couple of things but first user needs to choose sth and than content changes. I retrive array from strings.xml file that is ok. But I want to write strings.xml file an string-array but I can't do that? How can I do that?

Comment: Please read [ask] and post a [mre]. Your question is unclear. What do you want to write and where? What have you tried in order to achieve what you want and how is it working differently from what you expect?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. Strings.xml is only for storing predefined strings.You can use SharedPreferences or file to store your data.